# How can I prove this: "$\mathbb{P}^{n} \times \mathbb{A}^{m}$ is not affine variety$"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying prove this statement, but I can't realize what  I need to show first.
First I wanna take some isomorphism using one thing I know: "$\mathbb{A}² \backslash \{0,0\}$ is not affine.

Someone can give me a hint.

Thank all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A closed subset of an affine variety is affine, so this boils down to showing that $\mathbb{P}^n \times \{\ast\} \cong \mathbb{P}^n$ isn't affine.

Hint: What is its ring of globally-defined regular functions?

Comment: Ty so much bro, I finally proved this thing with your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

**Slade**'s answer is definitively the correct one.

Just to mention, since I assume the proof you know for $\mathbb{A}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is the cohomological one, you can show that $\mathbb{A}^n\times\mathbb{P}^n$ is not affine cohomologically. Indeed, just apply the Kunneth formula to, say, $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n}\boxtimes\mathcal{O}(-n-1)$.

Comment: I can't use Kunneth formula for this :c, that's so sad but I proved with the @Slade's answer :)

Ty